# UncaughtType error only in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, typeerror

I have the following code to animate a div.  It works perfectly:

```
function fadeAndSlideIn(el,m,t) {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    el.style.marginTop = 0;

    var oi = 1 / (t * 60);
    var mi = m / (t * 60);

    var tick = function() {
        el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + oi;
        el.style.marginTop = (parseInt(el.style.marginTop) + mi) + 'px';

        if (+el.style.opacity < 1)
            (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }

    tick();
}

(function() {
    fadeAndSlideIn(document.getElementById('pan1'),125,1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        fadeAndSlideIn(document.getElementById('pan2'),125,1);
    },500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        fadeAndSlideIn(document.getElementById('pan3'),125,1);
    },1000);
})();
```

However when I change the `fadeAndSlideIn` function to an anonymous function like this:

```
var fadeAndSlideIn = function(el,m,t) {
```

my program does not work and I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined

Why does the function decleration change the performance?  All the code is in a `<script`> tag at the end of the body.

Comment: Can you debug `el` and what's the ouput?

Comment: No value is returned from `fadeAndSlideIn`

Comment: I doubt this is the only change you are making.

Comment: could you please provide HTML or jsfiddle example?

Comment: @FelixKling This is the only change, I will make JSFiddle momentarily

Comment: did youve added ; at the end of the function expression?

Comment: Oh I see. The problems is that `()` is following the function expression. That will invoke the function immediately. Always terminate assignments with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS has got automatic semicolon insertion. This is not clever because sometimes the engine fails to do so and youre producing errors. So always use semicolons:

```
var a=function(){} //bad
var a=function(){}; //good
```

In your code the engine fails because as Felix Kling said, it thinks its an IIFE:

```
var a=function(){}
 (some other code);
```

So actually it passes your IIFE to the fadeInSlide as el, and el.style of your function is undefined...

Comment: Whoops I missed that!  Thank you

Comment: *"sometimes the engine fails to do so"* It doesn't "fail". ASI simply doesn't apply. There are well defined rules and if you don't know the rules, don't rely on ASI :)